# setHeader does nothing

Tags: node.js, express, http

I am making a little node.js web app, where styles and scripts obviously need to be loaded, this is what I have for one of the scripts:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/home.js", (req, res) => {
    readFile("./Scripts/home.js", (err, js) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send("We might have a problem here");
            console.log(err);
        }
        res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript; charset=utf-8")
        res.send(js);
    });
});
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log("App available on http://localhost:3000"));
```

As you can see, I set the Content type to `text/javascript; charset=utf-8`. But when I request the script in my html page in firefox, it has a `application/octet-stream` content-type, which is the default for firefox when it doesn't know the file type.

How do I make sure it is set to `text/javascript`?

EDIT: I could resolve this issue by setting the status to 200, but still have this problem with an image: `ìmage/png`, any idea?

Comment: try set header with Content-Type `application/javascript`

Comment: I found `text/javascript` on a mozilla page, but now when I look at iana.org, it indeed says application/javascript. Tnx! The png is listed as `image/png` though, any idea on what causes that to appear as `application/octet-stream`?

Comment: You should `return` or otherwise stop execution within your `if (err) { ... }` block.

Comment: Why are you manually handling static files like this? Just use `app.use(express.static("./Scripts"))`. See [Serving static files in Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)